# Getting a sorted window list

Tags: window, sorting

`(window-list)` returns a list of visible windows.  Is it possible to
get this list sorted from the most recently active window to the least?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by digging into `get-mru-window`, which uses `window-use-time`:

```
(sort (window-list)
      (lambda (a b) (> (window-use-time a)
                       (window-use-time b))))
```