# open buffers from sr-speedbar in previously active window instead of splitting window

Tags: window-splitting, speedbar

I'm using `sr-speedbar` to manage a list of buffers. After `M-x sr-speedbar-toggle`, I switch to the speedbar window, press `b` to switch into Quick Buffer mode, and then press `Enter` to select a buffer. In this example my main window is displaying `*scratch*` and I am pressing `Enter` on the `*Messages*` buffer.

I want `*Messages*` to open in the main window, but instead it opens in a new split window.

Here is how it appears before pressing Enter on the speedbar window:

[image: sr-speedbar before pressing Enter]

Actual behavior:
The `*Messages*` buffer opens in a new split window.

[image: sr-speedbar actual behavior]

Desired behavior:
The `*Messages*` buffer should open in the previously active window.

[image: sr-speedbar desired behavior]

How can I configure emacs to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Let us first identify the cause of the behavior observed by the original poster ... Open a current version of Emacs with no user-configuration (aka `Emacs -q`). Download `sr-speedbar.el` from Emacs wiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/sr-speedbar.el . Open the file `sr-speedbar.el` and type `M-x eval-buffer`. Now arrange the windows / buffers so that the `*Messages*` buffer exists (but is buried) and the `*scratch*` buffer is the *only* window visible.  Type `M-x sr-speedbar-toggle`.  Type `C-x o` to switch to the `*SPEEDBAR*` window....

Comment: Type the letter `b` to view the buffers in the `*SPEEDBAR*` window.  Place the cursor on the `*Messages*` buffer-name and type `M-x eval-expression RET` (aka `M-:`) and in the minibuffer type `(text-properties-at (point))` and `RET`.  [The output visible in the minibuffer is truncated `...`, but what we need just so happens to be visible.  To see what got truncated is beyond the scope of this example ....]  We observe the following output: `(speedbar-token t speedbar-function speedbar-buffer-click ...`. Now that we know the function name that we are interested in, ...

Comment: ... we can type `M-x find-function RET speedbar-buffer-click RET`.  We see two (2) possibilities with the `if/then` statement ... one if `dframe-power-click` is non-nil, and the other if it is nil ...  We start with the first option by going back to the `*SPEEDBAR*` window (because we do not *yet* know whether we are dealing with a buffer-local variable), and we type `M-x describe-variable RET` (aka `C-h v`) and type `dframe-power-click` and `RET`.  We see in the `*Help*` buffer that the variable is global (i.e., *not* buffer-local) and ...

Comment: ... we discover that it relates to a `S-mouse` activity situation, which does not apply to us.  By process of elimination, we now know that the portion of the function responsible for the behavior at issue is:  `(switch-to-buffer text)`.  We run a few more tests by going back to the `*SPEEDBAR*` window and evaluating `(window-dedicated-p`) and see that it is non-nil; i.e., the window is dedicated.  From the `*SPEEDBAR*` window with *only* the `*scratch*` buffer visible in the other window, we evaluate `(switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")` and observe the same behavior described by the O.P. ...

Comment: I am linking a recent question without an answer (at the moment, at least) entitled "*Getting a sorted window list*", as this current question contains component that appears to be similar:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/50463/2287